# REGEX: Add newline before Captial Letter without Period

Tags: jquery, regex, parsing

I'm parsing text, and I've split the text at newlines. But there are a few newlines I need to keep. Luckily, all of those newlines start with a capital letter, and are NOT preceded by a period.

Looking at other OS answers, I got `.replace(/(?<!.)[A-Z]/, /\n$0/);` which doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Example:

> Adam went for a walkEve took a nap.

into

> Adam went for a walk
>
> Eve took a nap.

Comment: Javascript doesn't support lookbehind, a feature included in your previous answer.  Is that why it isn't working?

Comment: could you give some lines as an example, in order to run some test?

Comment: can you provide us with a piece of the source string ?

Answer (score 1):

Problems in your code:

1. Javascript doesn't support `lookbehind`.
2. DOT will not match newline
3. replacement argument is a string

try this regex:

```
.replace(/(^|[\s\S])([A-Z])/g, "$1\n$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a regex like this:

```
replace(/([^\.])\n([A-Z])/g, "$1|$2")
```

It will replace the new lines that you want to keep with a pipe. Then you can do your split at the remaining new lines. And then convert these pipe characters back to new lines in the result.

To illustrate, I've put together a JSFiddle at **http://jsfiddle.net/tVR4b/**.

**Edit Based on Comment from Original Poster**

The modified regex would be:

```
.replace(/(\.)\n([A-Z])/g, "$1|$2");
```

And the modified JSFiddle is at **http://jsfiddle.net/tVR4b/2/**.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I want to give the newline to the lines without a period. Basically the reverse of what you did.

Comment: Okay, I've modified the answer to (I hope) implement what you're looking for.